# Styling Angular2 components based on the route

Tags: css, angular, angular-routing

I'm using a component called 'SearchComponent' in 2 routes. In the first route, the component is styled a certain way - for example there are 3 input texts that are `display:block` so they stack against each other. In the other route, I would like the 3 input texts to be inline-blocks.

The question is, can I use routing to conditionally change a components style?
I was hoping that the @Component decorator has some conditional logic capabilities but from my readings, it isn't possible. If that was the case, then I could just use a separate styleUrl path.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using route params? You could use some variable in the routes as a condition for the styling. For example:

```
 https://fooServer/fooApp/#/main/YourComponent;type=search1
```

Variable `type` here could be string, boolean, etc.. You would set it during the route change from the previous component.

Then in `ngOnInit()` you would call `this._route.snapshot.params['type'];` to grab the value in the route param. Then in the template, add to the tag `[attr.class]="type == search1? search1Class : search2Class"`

Info on route params [can be found here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) under the 'Route definition with a parameter' header.
Let me know if I misunderstood your question :)

Comment: awesome sauce. Works perfectly. Thank you!